# nHibernate and SQLite: Hibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite

I am getting the following error at runtime:
NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException: An exception occurred in the persistence layer.
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.AbstractBytecodeProvider.get_ProxyFactoryFactory()

Here is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory >
    <property name="connection.provider">
NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=audioHistory.sqlite</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
   <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataTransfer"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The file is copied to the output directory
I have a reference to NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle in the project
Fails on the line below

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
_sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();  // Fail
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Ups. Please reformat your question so that all of your config snippet appears as code.

Comment: do you actually have a newline inside the value of proxyfactory.factory_class?

Comment: also always post the full exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NHibernate 2.x, make sure you have a reference to Castle.Core.dll and Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll.

Or if you're using NHibernate 3.x, make sure you have a reference to Castle.Core.dll (Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll is no more)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using NHibernate 3.x I have refrences to Castle.Core (2.5.1) and NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle (3.0.0.3001). Unfortunately it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your configuration in a sample NHibernate project that I use for demos and it worked. So the problem isn't there.

Verify that the versions of the assemblies copied to the output directory are the same as shipped with NHibernate. I've had it happen that other libraries pull in their own dependencies, including a conflicting version of Castle.Core.dll or NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll. Unlikely, but something to check for.